# Несколько категорий у одной публикации

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

К новости необходимо присвоить 5-10 категорий, несколько.

Как это делаю я. В таблице новостей, добавляю поле, тип поля varchar(250).
В данном поле указываю через запятую id категорий. Неудобно то, что когда необходимо вывести новости одной категории, выборку делая через like и тут же.

id категорий у новости: `99,42,12`
Id категорий по которой выводим новости: `9`

Получается, что новости которые относятся к категории `99` тоже выберутся. Решаю это следующим образом, к строчке `99,42,12` добавляю запятые с начала и конца, получается `,99,42,12,`, а выборку делаю `,9,`

Что та мне подсказывает, что делаю я не верно. Поскольку ставить запятые и поиск по строчке занимает больше времени. А создавать отдельную таблицу в которой указывать к какой новости какие были присвоены категории, по моему тоже не верно.

Быть может подобные задачи решаются не путем добавления запятых и не путем создания доп.таблицы. Возможно это иначе делается?

Comment: про нормализацию почитайте. так делать не надо. сделайте перекрестную таблицу новость-категория, в ней может быть много записей как с одной категорией так и с одной новостью

Comment: Это называется связь "многие-ко-многим" и делается именно через третью таблицу.

Comment: *Решаю это следующим образом, к строчке 99,42,12 добавляю запятые с начала и конца, получается ,99,42,12,, а выборку делаю ,9,* Ну если не делать нормальную структуру и продолжать работать через одно место, то хотя бы используй предназначенную для такой операции функцию: ```.. WHERE FIND_IN_SET(@needed_id, CSV_column) ..```

Comment: Если делать через третью таблицу, в таком случаи придется при редактировании. Делать запрос на удалении записей из третьей таблицы, а затем вновь записывать. Что тоже неудобно...

Comment: [Cascade in SQL](https://www.scaler.com/topics/sql/cascade-in-sql/)